# AudioKit 5.2.2 midi not working in ios project, works in macos project

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, midi, audiokit

I'm using latest macOS, Xcode, Swift and AudioKit versions...

I set up MIDIListener to print any messages received. The only message received is "receivedMIDISetupChange".
Attempting to print any "noteOn" messages received.
It works in a macOS project but not in an ios project.
Please help!

```
import AudioKit
import UIKit
import CoreAudioKit
 

class ViewController: UIViewController, MIDIListener {
    
    let midi = MIDI()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        midi.openInput()
        midi.addListener(self)

        
    }
    
 
    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
                    print(noteNumber)
    }
    
    func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIController(_ controller: MIDIByte, value: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        print("receivedMIDIController")
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIAftertouch(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, pressure: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIAftertouch(_ pressure: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIPitchWheel(_ pitchWheelValue: MIDIWord, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIProgramChange(_ program: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        print("receivedMIDIProgramChange")
    }
    
    func receivedMIDISystemCommand(_ data: [MIDIByte], portID: MIDIUniqueID?, timeStamp: MIDITimeStamp?) {
        print("receivedMIDISystemCommand")
    }
    
    func receivedMIDISetupChange() {
        print("receivedMIDISetupChange")
    }
    
    func receivedMIDIPropertyChange(propertyChangeInfo: MIDIObjectPropertyChangeNotification) {
        print("receivedMIDIPropertyChange")
    }
    
    func receivedMIDINotification(notification: MIDINotification) {
        print("receivedMIDINotification")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jonny123,

Try adding `import CoreMIDI` into your ViewController's header.

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: unfortunately adding import CoreMIDI did not work... but thankyou for your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please post more of your code or a sample Xcode project? I can't tell how are you starting the AudioKit engine and applying its settings? Also, I would recommend having the audio engine/MIDI listener live within its own class and not a single ViewController. Are you planning to use AudioKit just for its MIDI capabilities, or are you planning to include sounds to be triggered via the MIDI that's being received?

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is actually the entire code I'm using which works on older versions of AudioKit. I also tested this identical code in a macOS project and it worked (received midi messages). I also tried placing the Listener in a separate class but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Are you triggering MIDI notes from an external MIDI controller, or are you using another iOS app that sends MIDI notes to your AudioKit app? Which version of iOS are you running on your device?

Comment: notes are triggered from an external MIDI controller. I've tried running iOS versions 11-15.

Comment: has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: @Jonny123. Do you have the option to upgrade the AudioKit framework to the latest version (5.3 at the moment)?

Comment: yes I am currently running the latest version 5.3

Comment: Are you implementing this with UIKit or SwiftUI? Have you seen the MIDI Monitor example in the AudioKit Cookbook? https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/MIDIMonitor.swift

Comment: I just tested the Cookbook and it works for me.

Comment: I'd be a little concerned attaching your midi listening to the view controller. Don't rely on the UI lifecycle for your audio and midi stuff. Other than that, Mark is right, without more context its hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I just downloaded and tested cookbook. Using the latest AudioKit and Xcode versions, I ran cookbook on the simulator-iPod touch (7th generation) and I connected my midi controller to MIDI Network Setup. I then selected "MIDI Monitor" and began playing notes on the controller. No response was received. What puzzles me is this exact setup works flawlessly on older versions of Xcode and AudioKit. I'm not sure what has changed or what I could be doing wrong...